# Good way to run ONE indefinite process on Django Framework

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I'm building a web app using a Django framework. There isn't much user interaction with only a few static links, navbar, and a few plots which come from my app itself. The main part of the app comes from a python script which reads data from an external source, does some data processing on it, and then writes to my django database. Then after writing to the database a new page is created with information about the database entry. Note that there is no user interaction so no starting or stopping the task. I want the task to run in the background 24/7.

Thus far I've looked into celery and django-background-tasks. Celery seems like a bit much for my use case. I don't think I need a broker service as I just want to run 1 task which the user will never interact with. Additionally, I don't need multiple workers. Django-background-tasks seems like a good lightweight alternative but it seems it does not support indefinite tasks without having to refresh the task every once in a while (ideally I don't want this). Is there a tool that is better suited for this use case? Or am I just completely misunderstanding celery and django-background-tasks.

**Update**
Thanks for the comments, everyone! So I looked up what was mentioned by @D Malan and I think a tool like Supervisord might fit my use case. That is I can run a python script separately from the django application in the background and then have the python script interact with the django application. The only problem I have now is getting the process to interact with the django app. @deceze mentioned invoking a manage command from the python script. So this would involve creating a subprocess from the python script calling a custom django management command which updates my database? Or can I use the django.core.management.call_command but from a python file separate from the django application. If this is the case how would it know where to get the command from?

Comment: Not posting this as an answer because I'm not super knowledgeable about it, but how about running your script with Supervisord? [This](https://serversforhackers.com/c/monitoring-processes-with-supervisord) is a nice tutorial.

Comment: Sounds like you might just need a *cron job*, which could invoke a Django management command which does the data processing?

Comment: Sounds like you just want a script with some infinite loop in it?

Comment: @DMalan Thanks for the response I think this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @deceze I like the django management command idea, but how can I call the command from my python script if the python script is outside the django project (see update)